# How to call methods from another class if my current class APIs are failing

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest

I need help with below. If my API1's method1 or method2 Fails and i want to call both the methods from API2 class to continue execution. How can i handle that. Can someone give me a some code idea?

```java
public class API1 (){

   public void method1(){

      /* generate token let's say 1234
     if token generation or method1 fails call both the methods of API2 class methodA & methodB */

   }

   public void method2(){

     /* if method1 generate successful token then pass the token 1234 from method1 and get the Acct nunber A777 from the Response
       if method2 passes then store the account number A777 and pass it to methodB of API2 class
       if this method2() fails for some reason call both the methods of API2 class methodA & methodB and continue execution with hard coded acctnumber from MethodB which is defined in the else statement
    }
}
```

```java
public class API2 {
                 
   public void methodA(){
      //Getting token auth toke let's 9876
   }

   public void methodB(){
      String OtherHardCodedAccountNumber = M999
      /* passing the token 9876 from methodA and pass the account number from API1 Class method2 which is A777 */

       if(method2 accountNunber is valid){
        use A777
        }
        else {
          // use the OtherHardCodedAccountNumber which is M999
        }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Please go through the guidelines of the fourm about [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also format your code properly for others to read. [Format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

Application defence mechanism should help you. Try [Netflix hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix).

Steps:
Perform execution of hystrix library:

```
 * API1.method1().  
 * API1.method2()
```

Throw exception if any of the methods fail. Hystrix does fallback whenever execution fails if fallback is enabled.

Perform fallback if execution has exceptions:

```
 * API2.method1().  
 * API2.method2()
```

[Netflix hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) basically provides all kinds of features for the application defence mechanism. Try it out.